# CodeIgniter $_POST data empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

First, relevant code:

---

**View**

```
<div id="search">
    <?= form_open('sheet/search') ?>

    <?= form_input('search_query', '', 'id="search_query" placeholder="Search Sheet Music"') ?>
    <?= form_submit('submit', 'Search!', 'class="hidden"') ?>

    <?= form_close() ?>
</div>
```

**Controller sheet/search**

```
public function search()
{
    if ($this->input->post('search_query'))
    {
    // blah
    // [ ... ]
```

`$_POST` is completely empty.

---

What on earth? The annoying thing is, other forms work perfectly fine on my website. Furthermore, this works perfectly on my testing server... so I'm guessing there's something wonky with my configuration files, .htaccess, or something. However, I don't know what could be causing it.

If you have an idea and need more information, feel free to specify. I just have no idea where to look, or what to change! Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

---

## EDIT 1/8/2013

Okay, I made a discovery. When my index page is removed from **config/config.php**, the search does not work. However, when it is added, it DOES work.

It still doesn't make any sense.

Below is my .htaccess file. Think I need to modify it somehow? I have absolutely no idea why it's not working still, but this is a step in the right direction.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|sheet|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You should not use "<?="...

Comment: @SureshKamrushi It's auto-enabled in PHP 5.4 and CodeIgniter auto-rewrites them if necessary.

Comment: How do you know that `$_POST` is completely empty? Do you `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: I did try a `var_dump($_POST)`. It was completely empty.

Comment: check input element in view source, is it building correctly?

Comment: It's building correctly. You can view here: http://apollomix.com. The search box is not sending POST data to the search controller.

Comment: what's the html outputted by CI's form generator? Have you checked if it's all correct?

Comment: You can view it in the source of the URL I provided. It is all correct.

Comment: Your form is posting to `http://apollomix.com/sheet/search.html`, and the `search_query` is being sent correctly, but that page is returning a 404 header.  Why is it doing that?  Also, are you sure you should have the `.html` in there?

Comment: It's returning a 404 header? That sounds like a step in the right direction. HOWEVER... that page clearly exists, as you can see by navigating to it. The .html shouldn't be a problem either, as CodeIgniter allows us to add a suffix to our URLs.

Comment: @NathanaelShermett: I don't know why it's not reading the `$_POST`.  The browser is sending it.  Maybe the page is being redirected and it's losing the data?

Comment: I ran into an issue like this once and it was annoyingly simple.  For some reason on my production server I had to include the www as part of the url where the form was posting to, other wise a 302 redirect was clearing the post array.

Comment: Are you doing some kind of routing for the sheet/search controller? I noticed if you add the search query as a paramater to the URL. Like so: `http://apollomix.com/sheet/search/world` The controller seems to work fine. Which could mean your routes need amending.

Comment: @JohnB: That's not the problem, because every other form is doing the same thing, and they're working fine.

Comment: @Jeemusu: there's no routing going on. What the script is supposed to do is get the POST data, sanitize it, and then redirect to a URL like the one above. However, since the POST data isn't showing up, it's not redirecting.

Comment: I found the problem! Thanks for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## AHA, I got it!

The problem was pretty sneaky. Apparently, because my `.htaccess` file was excepting the  `sheet` directory, AND the controller had the same name, things were going screwy with the CodeIgniter paths. What, exactly, I don't know. But it was bad, apparently!

To anyone in the future with this problem... make sure your `.htaccess` file isn't messing with your controllers!