# codeigniter posting form data not working on linux server

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, .htaccess, post

I recently changed my website Go-Daddy hosting to Dedicated Server which is LINUX server.

But, there is some problem on POST FORM Data...

I tried many ways on changing .ht-access.

There is no result in POST variables

```
$this->input->post ('variable');
Or
$_POST ['variable'];
```

These are returning empty values...

can you give any idea to solve this idea.

Comment: did you include form helper ?

Comment: code sample will be helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201815/codeigniter-post-data-empty

Comment: @balajimca yes. i loaded for helper.. but, not working...

Comment: @dianuj i tried above link... but, no result...

Comment: Paste the HTML portion of the form in your question.  What happens when you `var_dump($this->input->post());`

Comment: The same problem. form me. Not solution yet